# How we can create generic API in django?

Tags: python, django, api, generics, django-generic-views

I'm totally new to Django.

I'm creating **Generic API**. List and Create are working well but ID is not visible in DELETE and UPDATE.

This is my views.py file

> from rest_framework import generics

> from rest_framework import mixins

[image: This is my views.py]

This is my urls.py code

> from .views import GenericApiView

> path('inspections-templates', GenericApiView.as_view()),

But as I check documents the **ID** is not available for **UPDATE & DELETE**.

[image]

Can you please someone guide me on how can I update and delete the record.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to pass that id in your URL.Try this in urls.py:

```
path('inspections-templates/<int:id>/', GenericApiView.as_view()),
```

Because in UPDATE and DELETE user id is required to perform PUT and DELETE.

Comment: my new URL is => 
/api/v1/inspections-templates/{id} in all section like read, create, update and delete. And the new thing is list api is not visible.